# Searching from a platform without an Enter key (Zune HD)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the search box handheld-device friendly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/make-the-search-box-handheld-device-friendly)

Today as I was waking up I thought of a question to search for on Stack Overflow, and grabbed my Zune HD that was on my night stand.  I typed my query in the search box and hit "Done" (Zune HD's way of quitting the text-entry mode). Nothing happened.  I searched for a "Search" button, but none was found.  This left me unable to search on my Zune HD.

So I recommend adding a search button (I envision an arrow in a box to the right of the search box) so that platforms without an Enter key (such as the Zune HD) can effectively use Stack Overflow.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Any updates? This is still an issue.

Comment: waaaat?  I only got 9 upvotes, damnit.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/make-the-search-box-handheld-device-friendly/44192#44192

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you enter the search URL manually in to the Zune browser?  For example:

[`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=zune`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=zune)

You might also want to look at this question - [Make the search box handheld-device friendly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/make-the-search-box-handheld-device-friendly) - which is tagged as `status-declined`.

Comment: Hmm, this question is an exact duplicate but can't be closed because of the bounty. Maybe a moderator will take care of it.

Comment: Excellent tip! And sorry about the dupe, I searched for dupes (on my desktop, not my Zune) but didn't find anything. Go get yourself something nice with the points. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps make the little magnifying glass clickable, that way it doesn't require a change to the layout, or adding a new element.  New users might not find it readily, though, but it's not a feature that many people need.  (doesn't the zune HD have a virtual keyboard with an enter key?)

Comment: You mean the magnifying glass, and I agree it would not be very apparent. And no, the Zune HD does not have an Enter key on the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: you could alter the coloration or do a highlight-on-mouseover to indicate it's clickable.  or stick it on the right-hand side of the textarea instead of the left ("go" buttons tend to be on the right for left-to-right languages).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it would be useful.

You could also try downloading a better text entry tool, [like this one](http://www.softpicks.net/software/Comfort-On-Screen-Keyboard-35549.htm).

Comment: The problem is on a Zune HD, and thus I can't download an on-screen keyboard, I'm stuck with the one pre-loaded on the Zune.