# Is there a reason why we cannot have a search submit button?

Tags: discussion, search, user-interface

I've read numerous posts asking for a search submit button to be added which users can press/click to invoke a search rather than needing press enter.
Some have requested for accessibility reasons, some mobile browsing issues, but none seem to have had an official response, and some with "status-declined".

I was going to request this, but given the seemingly negative view on it, I thought I'd instead ask for an official response as to why it won't be implemented.

---

I wanted this as I quite often paste search terms into the search box *with my mouse*, and then want to click on results *with my mouse*.
While it's not arduous having to shift from *using my mouse* to press enter on the keyboard, it is a tad frustrating.
It would be much better to be able to paste *with my mouse*, press "Go" *with my mouse*, and then click on the result links *with my mouse*.

I believe the key UX I seek is *with my mouse*.

Is there any reason Stack Exchange seem to shy away from implementing this?

Comment: Here's the only [official response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26388/262755) I could find. It's not very popular, as you can see.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce - meta effect will likely make it even less popular. Still, we need some officially-looking red tag on this UX change request.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Thanks :) I found similar "[responses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62472/230506)" but no reason at all as to why. Happy if there is a reason, but seems odd given having no button is a problem/negative for some users, whereas having one there would surely bother no-one.

Comment: +1 The [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/12/designing-the-holy-search-box-examples-and-best-practices/) says: "Search Box = Input Field + Submit Button".

Comment: [We should be able to initiate a search using the mouse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269395/3541881) on MSO; userscript there if you want by @AstroCB...